# JSONModel loaddata post data in http body

Tags: sapui5

I tried to find out if there is really no way with JSONModel loaddata to do a HTTP post adding data (string/binary) to the http body.

While reading the docs (https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel#methods/Summary), testing and searching in stackoverflow/google it seems that there is no way?

I know that I can achieve it with default javascript/jquery ajax. The question is if it's also possible with loaddata method and if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

I dug a little deeper and noticed that `loadData` calls `jQuery.ajax` at some point.

https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/c782ce9be8cbd71201e19ba3cb4c0e81e439b71f/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/ClientModel.js#L130

So I tried the following

```
const oModel = new JSONModel();
oModel.loadData("https://httpbin.org/post", { key: "value" }, true, "POST");
```

This was the request body

[image]

and the response

[image]

Isn't this exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Marc, right now I would not agree with you. Additionally, you can already switch between the http methods, also setting it to POST. The only thing I not found is, to submit data in the http body instead of url parameters. When I would follow your argumentation that it doesn't make sense to implement other methods because it can already solved by e.g. ajax, than you could say it to everything which jquery and ui5 doubles like drag an drop etc... IMO that is no reason for me

Comment: One moment, you are right, I will completely change my answer.

Comment: Hi Marc, thx for your update. It comes near to what I want. I also already figured this out, but it automatically got switch to a multipart/form-data. I want and need to have the option to add binary code or just a json/xml/ascii string or form-data. But currently it seems that I stuck with form-data or url params.

Comment: Yes, seems like you are right. You could use inheritance to create your own BinaryJSONModel and overwrite this function to add binary support, but this is unfortunately not out of the box: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/3677a36d63c6a6160a6b15e3a5d3ea6e7e3eaf48/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel.js#L243